# i am getting error while installing mysqlclient on windows 10 no library is supproted

Tags: python, mysql, django

Running setup.py clean for mysqlclient
Failed to build mysqlclient
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: 'c:\users\uaahacker\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\uaahacker\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-icjkjmap\mysqlclient_8b5f49f509624395ab7dd2c4d4a21457\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\uaahacker\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-icjkjmap\mysqlclient_8b5f49f509624395ab7dd2c4d4a21457\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\uaahacker\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-62876lx5\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\uaahacker\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\Include\mysqlclient'
cwd: C:\Users\uaahacker\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-icjkjmap\mysqlclient_8b5f49f509624395ab7dd2c4d4a21457
Complete output (23 lines):
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win32-3.8
creating build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
creating build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
running build_ext
building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\uaahacker\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\uaahacker\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-icjkjmap\mysqlclient_8b5f49f509624395ab7dd2c4d4a21457\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\uaahacker\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-icjkjmap\mysqlclient_8b5f49f509624395ab7dd2c4d4a21457\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\uaahacker\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-62876lx5\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\uaahacker\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\Include\mysqlclient' Check the logs for full command output.

Answer (score 0):

There is no package on pypi for the 32-bit version of Python. Only for 64-bit Python.
And if you install mysqlclient from there, naturally, sources that need to be compiled will be installed.
And for 32-bit Python, the compiled package is available at [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/).

Answer (score -1):

**it is literally telling you how to solve the ptoblem in the error**

`error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/`

just download visualstudio build tools